# How to use MySQL "Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS" in Oracle to retrieve key values?

Tags: mysql, oracle, return-value, data-retrieval

I have the following MySQL query specified within a JSP. I want to figure out an equivelant query that I can run properly against Oracle Database as I am migrating my project from MySQL to Oracle DB.

Primary key of this "clips" table is "clip_id" which is actually not included in this query. In Oracle I created a sequence and trigger on "clip_id" because its value is supposed to auto-increment.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clips " +
        "(camera_id, num_recording, num_references, block_id_start,  
                    block_duration ) " +
        "VALUES ("+camera_id + ","+"1, " +
            "1,"+block_id_start + "," +
            block_duration + ");",
            Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

        rs = stmt.getGeneratedKeys();

        if( rs.next() )
        {
            clip_id = rs.getInt(1);
        }
```

Any comment or advice is appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: returning clip_id into v_clip_id ... see here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml_returning_into_clause.php

Answer (score 1):

To make my comment an answer:

Use the RETURNING INTO clause, see [here](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/dml_returning_into_clause.php).